# firestore with react native / expo in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have a weird bug.

Env :

- "expo": "~48.0.18",
- "react-native": "0.71.12",
- firebase: "^9.19.1",

In my signup form screen, I have this method :

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        const {name, email, phone, password} = data;

        try {
            // Créer un nouvel utilisateur avec l'email et le mot de passe fournis
            const {user} = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

            // Mettre à jour le profil de l'utilisateur avec les informations saisies
            await updateProfile(user, {
                displayName: name,
            });

            let tmpProfileType = profileType;
            if (profileType === "famille d'accueil") {
                tmpProfileType = "hostFamily";
            }

            // Sauvegarder les données de l'utilisateur dans Firebase Firestore
            const userRef = await doc(db, 'users', user.uid);

            const startDate = new Date();
            const endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 365));

            const userToInsert = {
                displayName: name,
                profileType:"test",
                phone,
                email,
                autonomous: false,
                BAFA:false,
                distance: 25,
                profileDescription,
                sent_in_active_campaign: false,
                uid: user.uid,
                loyaltyPoints: 1,
                loyaltyPointsHistory: [
                    {
                        date: new Date(),
                        label: 'Inscription',
                        nbPoints: 1,
                    }
                ],
                createdAt: new Date(),
                stripeId: "cus_0",
                subscriptionId: "free",
                periodStart: startDate,
                periodEnd: endDate,
            }

            console.log(userToInsert)

            await setDoc(userRef, userToInsert);

            // Redux avec les informations de l'utilisateur
            dispatch(setUser(userToInsert));

            // Naviguer vers l'écran suivant
            navigation.navigate('AddressScreen');
        } catch (err) {
            switch (err.code) {
                    case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                        setError("L'email est déjà utilisé")
                        break;
                    case 'auth/invalid-email':
                        setError("L'email est invalide")
                        break;
                    case 'auth/user-not-found':
                        setError("Vous n'avez pas encore créé de compte sur notre application")
                        break;
                    case 'auth/missing-password':
                        setError("Vous n'avez pas saisi de mot de passe")
                        break;
                    case 'auth/wrong-password':
                        setError("Le mot de passe n'est pas bon")
                        break;
                    default:
                        setError("Il y a eu un souci. Notre équipe en a été informée.")
                        Bugsnag.notify(err)
                        break
                }
        }
    }
```

createUserWithEmailAndPassword => OK

updateProfile => OK

But after, I have no logs and iOS app is always crashing ...

- In Expo Go => OK
- In Android (testing / production) => OK
- In Expo Go with iOS => OK
- In TestFlight => NOK
- In iOS production => NOK

How to solve it ?

Thank you very much for your answer :)

Thibaut